# 3D model in game developement

Tags: game

salam alaykoum , i'am willing to make a video game that include 3D model such as trees..human like 
is it haram or halal to make a tree anything related to allah creatures ?

game theme : 5 players tries to reach a specific place and the other 5 dont have to let them 
thanks